# Получение корневого родителя элемента

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует такая иерархия

- `canvas_main`

  - `canvas_second`

    - `Image`
  - `Image`

На обоих `Image` висит один и тот же скрипт, как из него получить `canvas_main`?

Очевидно что просто `transform.parent.gameObject` не подходит в силу "разноуровности" элементов.

Comment: Ну а если итерацией или рекурсией перебирать родителей, пока не null?

Comment: @Mike можно конечно, но хотелось как-то по красивше

Comment: Ну а просто закешировать: public GameObject mainCan; или GameObject.Find("canvas_main") или GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("TagMainCanvas"); почему не хотите?

Comment: @Mike я использовал поиск по тегу, но почему то вылетала NullExc в юнити все работало а при сборке  и запуске проекта нет, так и не смог понять почему, сейчас сделал итерацией - работает. Вроде даже не так плохо, но меня беспокоит ресурсоемкость такого метода, мне казалось по тегу самый менее затратный способ, а Вы как считаете?

Comment: по поводу NullExc могу только предположить что у вас поиск по тэгу идет, например, в Start(), а обращение к объекту в OnEnable() (OnEnable выполняется раньше Start), например, или в том же Start() другого скрипта (а тогда не угадаешь, какой старт выполнится раньше), ну используйте как public GameObject переменную или как [SerializeField] private GameObject и задайте переменную ручками.

Answer (score 1):

Все GameObject обязаны иметь компонент Transform, а у всех классов наследников MonoBehaivior есть метод GetComponentsInParent(). Который вернёт все компоненты данного типа, которые найдёт идя вверх по списку.

Могу, конечно, ошибиться, но этот метод при вызове .GetComponentsInParent() вернёт вам массив из трансформов, в котором последним элементом будет самый верхний трансформ. Как следствие из него вы можете получить объект через .gameObject

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, наимение ресурсоёмкий способ это ссылка прямо на объект.

```
public Transform MainParent;
```

Если вам этот способ не нравится, вы можете найти по тегу или названию.

Answer (score 0):

Если над canvas_main нет других объектов, то можно же просто transform.root использовать